# Problem with CORS Policy when call to API with SPFx

Tags: spfx, azure, api, cors

have problem with CORS Policy. Get an error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://XXX.azurewebsites.net/api/protocols' from origin 'https://localhost:4321' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I removed custome headers but an error still occurs.

```
const httpClientOptions: IHttpClientOptions = {
  headers: new Headers(),
  method: "GET",
  mode: "cors"
};
    
export default class ProtocolsWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IProtocolsWebPartProps> {

  public render(): void {
   

    this.domElement.innerHTML = `
      <div class="${ styles.protocols }">
        <div class="${ styles.container }">
          <div class="${ styles.row }">
            <div class="${ styles.column }">
               <div>${this.getJsonData()}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>`;
  }

  public getJsonData = () => {
    this.context.httpClient
    .get('https://integroprotocolsapp.azurewebsites.net/api/protocols', HttpClient.configurations.v1, httpClientOptions)
    .then((response: HttpClientResponse) : Promise<any> => {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json();
      
    })
    .then((response: any): void => {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

Do you have any idea how to avoid CORS Policy in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webapp that you are trying to access should allow requests made by your web part. You need to check the CORS policy configured for the web app/API that you are trying to access and allow request from your SharePoint tenant URL.

[image]

Comment: Oh great. That's really help me. Thank you.